# error in installing DotNetNuke

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, dotnetnuke

i have problem in installing dot net nuke on iis 7 and sql server 2008 express

```
 0:04 Minutes   |   15% ERROR occured - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@ParentId".
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Here's what I found.

I was attempting to connect to a SQL Server instance where case-sensitivity is enforced. The script files provided with DNN 7.00.06 have a number of inconsistencies in regards to case. An example is the parameter @ParentId, which is declared @ParentID. I was not permitted to alter the settings on the remote SQL Server so I ended up installing a local SQL Express (with case-sensitivity off) as a work-around.

I hope my experience helps if anyone else comes across this issue.